# angular2 using twitter module from npm

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, angular

I had problem with LODASH importing to Angular2 app, got answer [on this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35130682/angular2-failing-lodash-import/35131266#35131266) and all working now.

Next problem I have is that I do not know how to make "twitter" npm module to work within the app.

Now I installed "npm install twitter" and tried to import it with:

```
import * as Twitter from 'twitter';
```

but I get "cannot find module 'twitter'. I tried adding to system.config without luck.

What am I doing wrong here? How should the code look like for import and using this twitter module?

Here is system.config in index.html:

```
  System.config({
    packages: {
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    },
    map: {
      lodash: 'node_modules/lodash/lodash.js',
      twitter: 'node_modules/twitter/index.js'
    },
    meta: {
      lodash: { format: 'amd' },
      twitter: { format: 'amd' }
    }
  });
```

Comment: looks like a issue with your systemjs config, its better to post it as well in the question

Comment: The NPM module you're trying to import (`npm install twitter`) is a client side API which is meant to be used in NodeJS.

Comment: `import Twitter from './twitter/index';` won't work?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to add the definition file of the twitter module to a typings folder. Or install it using tsd. After that you can use it in your typescript code using a reference:

**download manually**

1. Download the definition file from [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/ffceea9dd124d277c4597c7bd12930666ec074c5/twitter/twitter.d.ts)
2. Add it to a typings folder in your source root

or

**install using tsd**

1. Open cmd in source folder
2. `npm install tsd -g`
3. `tsd install twitter --save`

After that add the reference in the top of your typescript file

```
/// <reference path="../typings/twitter.d.ts"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The twitter module is a commonjs module, so it won't work with amd. Try the following config to see if it works:

```
System.config({
  packages: {
  app: {
    format: 'register',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
},
map: {
  lodash: 'node_modules/lodash/lodash.js',
  twitter: 'node_modules/twitter'
},
meta: {
  lodash: { format: 'commonjs' },
  twitter: { format: 'commonjs' }
}
});
```

try the import like this:

```
import * as Twitter from 'twitter/index';
```

Does it work? I don't think lodash is an amd module as well, its also commonjs. You probably can remove the full meta section, systemJs will auto-detect the type of module system successfully most of the times.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could use this module in such scenario as its a server-side module and needs Node running. I've managed to implement twitter authentication using other module:
https://github.com/jublonet/codebird-js

I've been working for a while on a simple project implementing social media logins. If you want you can take a look at:
https://github.com/bkulov/EventOrgApp