# Lodash in angular2, declare var_:any not working

Tags: angular, lodash

I am using lodash in my angular2 app. by using `declare var _: any;` i am doing lodash operation such as `_.findIndex(...)` . Now i am facing one issue. sometimes while loading page i am getting error as below

```
EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: _ is not defined
```

how to avoid this?
As my assumption, lodash code is executed before `declare var _: any;`

Comment: is it necessary to use lodash this way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular2 failing lodash import](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35130682/angular2-failing-lodash-import)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, it depends on the way to configure / include the lodash library into your HTML page:

- **Include the lodash.js file into a `script` element**. This way, lodash is available as a global variable (`_`) into the application. In this case, you need to define it leveraging ambient declarations of TypeScript:

  ```
  declare var _: any;
  ```
- **Configure the lodash.js file into the SystemJS configuration**. In this way, the lodash library will detect that it will be used within a module loader so it will register itself as a module and return the `_` variable into exports. In this case, you need to use an import to get it. Since the `_` variable is directly set into exports, you need to import it this way:

  ```
  import _ from 'lodash';
  ```

  The corresponding configuration would be:

  ```
  System.config({
    (...)
    map: {
      lodash: 'node_modules/lodash/lodash.js'
    },
    meta: {
      lodash: { format: 'amd' }
    }
  });
  ```

Comment: Can't we use it directly with `<reference ...>` at the top of the component?

Comment: In fact, `reference`s are only for compilation to import the contract of the library... It's not for runtime.

Comment: Still I'm not clear with it. look I have made this, http://plnkr.co/edit/3xEZBpwz6NCMU1uxBg5O?p=preview can you tell me what is wrong with it? I don't understand what do you mean by `runtime`?

Comment: In your case, you included lodash within a script element so the `_` variable is directly available. Since you use the on-the-fly transpiling, you don't see the errors ;-) but with tsc, I guess that you will have some. You should add the `declare var _: any` and the `<reference` provide the contract for the `_` variable. By runtime I mean when executing the application...

Comment: Oh I see. I have to check that.

Comment: I am using this seed project [link](https://github.com/shivanshuag/angular2-seed). In this project there is no system.config. can you please explain how to do this?

Comment: In my porject there is no systemjs how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using TypeScript, then you need to import the library in your file:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
```

Have a look at a simular question:
[angular2 failing lodash import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35130682/angular2-failing-lodash-import)