# Angular2 dependency not injecting correct path

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I am getting the following errors in my browser console, from trying to use localStorage with Angular2. It seems that the path it is generating isn't referring to the node_modules, but rather assuming that there is a localstorage.js in my site root (which there isn't). I am just referring to it normally (see my user.service below), so how do I get around this? All my other dependencies are working fine.

> Error loading http://localhost:3000/localStorage.js as "localStorage" from http://localhost:3000/client/dev/user/services/user.service.js

[image]

```
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { Headers } from 'angular2/http';
import { loalStorage } from 'localStorage';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  private loggedIn = false;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.loggedIn = !!localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
  }

}
```

NB: I am fairly sure there isn't an actual problem with the localStorage installation, as if I run `npm list localStorage`, then it tells me I have `localStorage@1.0.3` instaled.

Comment: You did really installed a library for something that's builtin in the browser?

Comment: @EricMartinez Otherwise, how do I get code like `localStorage.getItem('auth_token')` to work?

Comment: [MDN localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use localStorage from an import, you need to configure it within SystemJS as described below:

```
System.config({
  map: {
    localStorage: 'node_modules/localStorage/lib/localStorage.js'
  },
  (...)
});
```

This way, you will be able to use the following import:

```
import loalStorage from 'localStorage';
```

See this question for more details since it's similar to the way to configure Lodash:

- [Lodash in angular2, declare var_:any not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36171727/lodash-in-angular2-declare-var-any-not-working/36173035#36173035)